# What is the name of this proof technique?

Tags: logic

Let's say I have an algebraic statement A that I need to prove or disprove.
Then I assume A and manipulate it to get the statement B. So, I have A implies B. Then I prove that B is false. Therefore, A must be false for the implication to be true.

Is this just called contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** proof by contradiction. It is proof by [*ex falso quodlibet* (EFQ) or *explosion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion): you have assumed $A$, derived a contradiction (false) from that and concluded that $A$ is false. A [proof by contradiction of $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) would first assume that $A$ is false. The distinction is important: EFQ is acceptable in intuitionistic/constructive logic, but proof by contradiction is not.

Answer (score 0):

No it's called proof by contrapositive. It's an instance of the following scheme : 
$(P\implies Q) \implies (\neg Q \implies \neg P)$

Comment: What you mean is contraposition.

Comment: Rob : he said he showed $A\implies B$. Therefore he has $\neg B \implies \neg A$. Moreover he proved $\neg B$. Modus ponens allows him to conclude $\neg A$. How is this wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

NO.  This is called ***proof by*** contradiction, also known by the Latin phrase *reductio ad absurdum* (rough literal translation: 'reducing to an absurdity').  Calling it simply *contradiction* would suggest that a genuine mathematical inconsistency had been arrived at, which is *not* what is intended or what has actually been achieved.

@Rob Arthan - Actually, you do not need to assume A is false and then deduce a contradiction to show A is true; you can just as easily do it the other way around.  If that makes you uncomfortable, reinterpret it as showing (NOT A) is true instead.

Comment: No, it's not. See my answer.

Comment: @RobArthan - NOTE: I am not a constructivist.

Comment: See my answer and the links therein. EFQ (aka. explosion or *reductio ad absurdum*) and proof by contradiction are not the same thing and the difference is important. Whether or not you are a constructivist is irrelevant to your correct use of the terminology of mathematical logic.